# *NgIf for showing a dropdown

Tags: angular

How can I use *Ngif to show a dropdown and hide another one. using the input of a checkbox.

So if checkbox is true show this else show that.

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="test1">
        <div class="test-header">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="test-block">
            <app-select
                (selectConnection)="onSelectConnection($event)"
                (selectPeriod)="onSelectPeriod($event)"
                (selectUtilityType)="onSelectUtilityType($event)"
                (selectTime)="onSelectTime($event)"
                [timeSelection]="true"
                [utilityTypeSelection]="true"
                [allowTimeToggle]="true"
                [allowAll]="true"
                [periodSelection]="true"
                [allowTableToggle]="false"
                [intervalSelection]="false"
                [parentIsLoading]="loading"
            ></app-select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ToggleTime is a boolean for the checkbox

So something like this

```
*Ngif="ToggleTime(is true)"
```

Show:

```
[timeSelection]="true" 
[periodSelection]="false"
```

And the rest.

if not

```
*Ngif="!ToggleTime"
[timeSelection]="false"
[periodSelection]="true"
```

And the rest.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
[timeSelection]="ToggleTime? true:false" 
[periodSelection]="ToggleTime? false:true"
```

or much simpler:

```
[timeSelection]="ToggleTime" 
[periodSelection]="!ToggleTime"
```

(use second approach, but the first one is worth to know and will be useful later)

Comment: Solved, Thanks, the first example i will probably use in the future.

Comment: any time my friend.:)

Answer (score 0):

Use the value that the checkbox is bound to directly. Assuming that is `ToggleTime`:

```
[timeSelection]="ToggleTime" 
[periodSelection]="!ToggleTime"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
[timeSelection]="ToggleTime" 
[periodSelection]="!ToggleTime"
```